# Moving Bus Icon on Google Map Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

I'm using Javascript Google Map. I want to add a moving bus icon as the map marker will reload a new location every 5 seconds. Everything is running perfectly. I just want to add an icon that will look like a real bus, which will move on the road.

I did search for that and found the following code:

```
var car='M29.395,0H17.636c-3.117,0-5.643,3.467-5.643,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759   c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644V6.584C35.037,3.467,32.511,0,29.395,0z M34.05,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L34.05,14.188z    M32.618,10.773c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H16.631l-2.222-8.51C14.41,10.773,23.293,7.755,32.618,10.773z M15.741,21.713   v4.492l-2.73-0.349V14.502L15.741,21.713z M13.011,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L13.011,37.938z M14.568,40.882l2.218-3.336   h13.771l2.219,3.336H14.568z M31.321,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L31.321,35.805';
```

**My Question is:**
how can I generate the same icon/code for a school bus?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you provided is a SVG path. You can create your own SVG path that draws a bus and then use that code to create the bus.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M29.395,0H17.636c-3.117,0-5.643,3.467-5.643,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759   c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644V6.584C35.037,3.467,32.511,0,29.395,0z M34.05,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L34.05,14.188z    M32.618,10.773c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H16.631l-2.222-8.51C14.41,10.773,23.293,7.755,32.618,10.773z M15.741,21.713   v4.492l-2.73-0.349V14.502L15.741,21.713z M13.011,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L13.011,37.938z M14.568,40.882l2.218-3.336   h13.771l2.219,3.336H14.568z M31.321,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L31.321,35.805" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Run the provided code to see the drawn car in SVG.

Comment: Thank you so much, Gil Fink. Can you suggest any website from where I can get SVG Icon? Thanks

Comment: @GauravNarula you can get lots of free icons at The Noun Project https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=bus

Comment: Thank you so much @Gil Fink. You saved my day :)

Comment: In what does that answer the question? You should at least include your comment in the answer itself. And you might add that many software (such as Photoshop, Gimp, etc.) allow to save an image as SVG and that any text editor can open an SVG file to access its path(s).